# Line Voltage Dropping when Microwave runs

Tags: electrical

When I turn on the built-in Microwave in a 3 years old house it starts and then in 2-3 sounds the changes and it is apparent that something is wrong. The microwave does not heat.
Then I noticed that the gas range electronic display was turning on and off when the microwave was turned on. I took out the multimeter and there is 20 Volts drops when the microwave is running! 
No trips in the circuit and the damn Microwave and Gas Range are not even on the same circuit. 
What could be going on?? Should I be worried?!

Comment: How did you measure the voltage with a multimeter? Do you have an RMS AC multimeter? Those are quite expensive and I would imagine if you had one of those you probably wouldn't be asking this question...

Comment: First thing to look for/eliminate is a loose connection (or bad backstab connection).

Comment: Check other receptacles in your house.  Are any of them going *over*voltage by about the same amount?  If so shut off your main breaker immediately and call the power company and report a power failure.  This is a type of power failure called a lost neutral, that is dangerous because the overvoltage can be much worse and fry things.

Comment: This is not a forum, it's a question and answer site.  If you want to reply to a question/answer, please use a comment.  If an answer to your question was correct, you can vote it up by clicking the up arrow next to the answer.  You can also mark the answer as correct (on your own questions), by clicking the check mark next to the answer. Please take the [tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour), and read through the [help center](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more about how StackExchange sites work.

Answer (score 5):

With these being on 2 different circuits call your power company and report a problem. You could have lost a leg or a neutral , you could listen for arcs and sparks in your panel but if you keep trying appliances they may all get fried if the service neutral opened.

Comment: Thank you all for great input. I called as advised and got lucky that utility company had a crew nearby. You called it - service neutral fault. Microwave and garage fridge are toast :( I used a multimeter that I picked from a local hardware store some years ago. It is nothing special or expensive. Great forum and I will pay it forward!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much current your microwave draws (1000W - 1200W??) it may be drawing enough power to cause some modest voltage drops, especially if you have other appliances or loads on other circuits in the house.

And with a house of that age, it may have had some unauthorized wiring done at some time, too, which may be adding to the problems you are experiencing.

It may be a good idea to have a LICENSED ELECTRICIAN (verify license) come in and take a look around.  They will probably recommend a re-wire of the house, which won't be cheap, but in the long run you will have a much more livable house, not to mention safer place to live.

This is one of those cases where you can get by for a while, but get an inspection at least, even if you don't have the work done right away.

At least, you won't find yourselves crispy critters in the middle of the night due to some unknown electrical fault.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. I'm not sure where you got that the questioner only has 60 amp circuit. It also doesn't matter how much power the gas range draws, as its ("electronic") display was being affected even when the unit was (presumably) off. I've edited these areas out.

Answer (score 0):

I just re-read the original post, and you are correct, unlikely that in a 3-year old house the service would be that small. I missed the important detail "3 years old house".

In any case, it certainly bears investigation and a checkup by somebody who knows what they are doing.